# Confusion in ThreadPoolExecutor.afterExecute() example code

Tags: java, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I am reading about `ThreadPoolExecutor.afterExecute()` and in the process found example code in JDK which looks like

```
  class ExtendedExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
   // ...
   protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
     super.afterExecute(r, t);
     if (t == null && r instanceof Future) {
       try {
         Object result = ((Future) r).get();
       } catch (CancellationException ce) {
           t = ce;
       } catch (ExecutionException ee) {
           t = ee.getCause();
       } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
           Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // ignore/reset
       }
     }
     if (t != null)
       System.out.println(t);
   }
 }}
```

The code in the javadocs mentions

```
 r instanceof Future<?>
```

and

```
result = ((Future<?>) r).get()
```

From Understanding there should be **FutureTask** instead of Future.

r is a Runnable and Future doesn't implement Runnable but FutureTask does and is mentioned in the javadocs

If any one can please help me clear the clouds as i am confused here.

Comment: If you see the check it will always fail.. as r istanceof future will result in false.

Comment: why? What if the object is both a `Runnable` and a `Future`?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to implement two interfaces at once. If the `Runnable` object also implements `Future`, then we can perform special handling of that object by casting it (after checking the cast will be fine). In the case of `FutureTask<V>` objects, these implement both `Runnable` and `Future<V>` and so the logic there will apply to them.

Edit: Not sure why the downvote but I suppose that means I better clarify

```
FutureTask<String> f = new FutureTask(
                          () -> { System.out.println("Hey"); },
                          "Hi");
f instanceof Runnable; // true
f instanceof Future; // true
executor.submit(f);
// Executor will call afterExecute(f, null) after running f.
// Prints:
// Hey
// Hi
```

The "Hi" is from the inside of the `if` statement which you're unsure if it ever gets executed (assuming that we're adding a print statement to the value of `result`, ie) `f.get()`)

Answer (score 1):

ThreadPoolExecutor.afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) 
here r can be runnable in case u call executor.execute() or r can be a futureTask in case call is executor.submit().
FutureTask implements RunnableFuture which in turn extends Runnable and Future

So, intanceof holds true for Runnable and Future in case submit is called.

Answer (score 0):

FutureTask implements RunnableFuture,and RunnableFuture extends Runnable, Future,so it is the reseaon why you post FutureTask but can be cast to Future

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reasoning behind just saying `Future` instead of `FutureTask` is that it's the most general thing we accept here.

Although in practice it most likely will be a `FutureTask`, it doesn't **have** to be.

Let's say purely for the sake of an example that `r` is an instance of the following class:

```
public class MyExample implements Runnable, Future {
    ....
}
```

The `afterExecute(r,t)` will work just fine, but `r` is **not** an instance of `FutureTask`